# Why is a Queue<Integer> returning an Iterable<Integer> here?

Tags: java, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs, topological-sort

Context:

I am reading chapter 4 of Sedgewick & Wayne's Algorithms. 
This code example is a code example of "Depth-first search vertex ordering in a digraph".

```
        public class DepthFirstOrder
        {
            private boolean[] marked;
            private Queue<Integer> pre; // vertices in preorder
            private Queue<Integer> post; // vertices in postorder
            private Stack<Integer> reversePost; // vertices in reverse postorder
            public DepthFirstOrder(Digraph G)
            {
                pre = new Queue<Integer>();
                post = new Queue<Integer>();
                reversePost = new Stack<Integer>();
                marked = new boolean[G.V()];
                for (int v = 0; v < G.V(); v++)
                    if (!marked[v]) dfs(G, v);
            }
            private void dfs(Digraph G, int v)
            {
                pre.enqueue(v);
                marked[v] = true;
                for (int w : G.adj(v))
                    if (!marked[w])
                        dfs(G, w);
                post.enqueue(v);
                reversePost.push(v);
            }
            public Iterable<Integer> pre()
            { return pre; }
            public Iterable<Integer> post()
            { return post; }
            public Iterable<Integer> reversePost()
            { return reversePost; }
        }
```

My question is why the Queues are returned as Iterables in their respective methods for retrieval.
I get what the code does otherwise, but what I don't understand is why **pre**, **post** and **reversePost** are returning an Iterable here while they are Queues?

I understand what the Iterable interface normally does, and that a Queue is also an Iterable because Collection implements Iterable.

I don't understand however, why this implementation is returning the Queues as Iterables.

Comment: What are these methods even used for?

Answer (score 3):

It's so that the external interface only promises that those are `Iterable`, not specifically that they're `Queue`s. This means:

1. The implementation can change without affecting the interface the class provides.
2. Users of the returned queues can only rely on them being `Iterable`s, they can't assume they're `Queue`s, specifically. (Which amongst other things means the can't use state-mutating features `Queue` provides beyond the one [`remove`] that `Iterable` does — not without casting them, which would be a Bad Thing™ because all that the class guarantees is that they're `Iterable`s, not that they're `Queue`s.)

A more defensive class might insert a facade between the actual `Queue` and the returned object to defend against poorly-written code doing #2 above, but of course, there's a cost there.

Comment: "state-mutating features" `Iterable` may still allow access to `remove()` (via the iterator).

Comment: @AndyTurner - Well, I did say "...`Queue` provides...that `Iterable` doesn't." :-) But I do tend to forget that `Iterable` has `remove`...

Comment: I think we all forget that at times... :D